# Inserting a node in the given position c++

Tags: c++, insert, linked-list

I have a problem about inserting an element in a given position in a single linked list. Actually the problem is only at inserting into middle part,
Here is my insert function;

```
void SimpleList::insert (const ItemType & item, int position){        
    Node* prev = NULL;
    Node* curr = NULL;
    Node* newNode = new Node();
    newNode->data = item;

    int tempPos = 0;

    curr = head;

    if(head != NULL){
        while(curr->next != NULL && tempPos != position)
        {
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
            tempPos++;
        }
        if(position==1)
        {
            newNode->next=head;
            head=newNode;
            size++;

        }
        else if(curr->next == NULL)
        {

            curr->next = newNode;
            last = newNode;
            newNode->next= NULL;
            size++;
        }
        else
        {
            prev->next = newNode;
            newNode->next = curr;
            size++;
        }
    }
    else  {
        last = head = newNode;
        last->next = NULL;
        size++;
    }
}
```

and the output of my test code is;

```
after insert into empty list: should be 34
34  
after insert at beginning: should be  45, 34
45  34  
after inserts in middle: should be 45, 72, 56, 34
45  34  56  72  
after insert at end: should be 45, 72, 56, 34, 67
45  34  56  72  67
```

How can I fix that problem?
Thank you all for your helps.

Comment: First of all try to figure it all out on paper first, and try to reimplement the function using the algorithm you come up with on paper. Then if you have problems learn how to use a debugger, and step through the code line by line to see what it does.

Comment: Also, please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you can show us, which include how you call the function and with what values.

Comment: Are you using your indexing base consistently? Both position 0 and position 1 will insert at the head of the list by the looks of it, which is a strange design decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your question is a homework question.  I am going to answer using the homework answering guideline:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Your while loop depends on 2 things.

- the length of a linked list, which sets the values of prev/curr
- the position argument value

The if-elseif-else statements afterwards depend on the while loop results of setting of the values of prev/curr and the position argument value.

You have to make sure that the while loop is correct, and afterwards, the if-elseif-else statements are correct.

To make sure the while loop and the following if-elseif-else statements are correct, think about whether or not they are correct in all combinations of

- the length of a linked list, which sets the values of prev/curr
- the position argument value

The length of a linked list can be 0, 1, ...
The position argument value can be 0, 1, ...

When length=1, position=0, the while loop is not iterated, and the program executes `else if(curr->next == NULL)`, the resultant linked list has the new node to be *after* the original first node.

When length=1, position=1, the while loop is not iterated, and the program executes `if(position==1)`, the resultant linked list has the new node to be *before* the original first node.

When length=2, position=0, the while loop is not iterated, and the program executes `else`. `prev=NULL`, so `prev->next` results in a segmentation fault.

When length=2, position=1, the while loop is iterated once, and the program executes `if(position==1)`. the resultant linked list has the new node to be *before* the original *first* node.

When length=2, position=2, the while loop is iterated once, and the program executes `else if(curr->next == NULL)`. the resultant linked list has the new node to be *after* the original *second* node.

The above cases show the cases where the while loop and the following if-elseif-else statements result in linked lists that probably are not the correct ones.

To fix the problem, think about how to design the while loop and the if-elseif-else statements so that for all combinations of the length of a linked list and the position argument values, the program is going to insert the new node in the correct position.

I am not very sure the position argument value for inserting at beginning, inserting in middle, and inserting at end.  You may have to verify the linked list status yourself after taking a look of my answer.

The code inside the while loop and if-elseif-else statements is run for all combinations of the length of a linked list and the position argument value.  When you design the code, make sure the code works for all combinations.